# Convert public List<List<List<double>>> to string comma separated using C#

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

Using C#, I have the following list of doubles:

```
public List<List<List<double>>> doubles { get; set; }
```

I need to convert it to a string using the following format:

```
[
    [-118.818984489994, 34.0137559967283], 
    [-118.806796597377, 34.0215816298725], 
    [-118.791432890735, 34.0163883241613], 
    [-118.79596686535, 34.008564864635],  
    [-118.808558110679, 34.0035027131376]  
]
```

This is what I have so far but it is not working (Stores the text "System.Collections.."):

```
string result = string.Join(",", doubles.SelectMany(i => i));
```

Any help would be appreciated to convert the list of doubles to one string in this format:

```
[
    [-118.818984489994, 34.0137559967283], 
    [-118.806796597377, 34.0215816298725], 
    [-118.791432890735, 34.0163883241613], 
    [-118.79596686535, 34.008564864635],  
    [-118.808558110679, 34.0035027131376]  
]
```

Comment: Are you attempting to convert to JSON? There are libraries and built-in methods for that. Where are the `[`,`]` in your sample code?

Comment: Will you please include a same original dataset? I'm assuming these are Malibu lat./long. coordinates, but how is this structured in your nested lists?

Comment: Clarification what level need to be flattened would help (re-read the [mre] guidance to see what is expected in sense of expected/actual values). Also if you can clarify how you expect regex to be involved in the answer it may help shaping answers more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to make an array look like this is to serialize the array into a json string using the *Newtonsoft.Json* package. Looks like that

```cs
var input = new List<List<List<double>>> {
            new List<List<double>>() {new List<double> {-118.818984489994, 34.0137559967283}},
            new List<List<double>>() {new List<double> {-118.818984489994, 34.0137559967283}},
            new List<List<double>>() {new List<double> {-118.818984489994, 34.0137559967283}},
            new List<List<double>>() {new List<double> {-118.818984489994, 34.0137559967283}},
        };

var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input);
    
Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
```

Comment: Note that OP asking for 2 level array for some unclear reason in the output while code here sensibly provides 3 levels of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You want to call `SelectMany` *twice*:

```
string result = string.Join(",", doubles
  .SelectMany(item => item)
  .SelectMany(item => item));
```